# Python Google Colab notebooks, filenotfounderror when using ImageDataGenerator Flow_from_directory

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

I am getting a file not found error when trying to run ImageDataGenerator flow_from_directory in Google Colab Notebooks.

The strange thing is it works on the first run but then when I reload the data into base_dir it gives the error.

Here is the code I use to read the data into Notebooks

```
_URL = "http://xxxxx/images/Model_images_40.tar.gz"

zip_file = tf.keras.utils.get_file(origin=_URL, 
                                   fname="Model_images_40.tar.gz", 
                                   extract=True)

base_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(zip_file), 'Model_images_40')
```

Here  is what base_dir looks like

```
'/root/.keras/datasets/Model_images_40'
```

Then here is the next bit of code I run to get the training and testing data (but it gives the error below)

```
IMAGE_SIZE = 224
BATCH_SIZE = 64

datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255, 
    validation_split=0.35)

train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    base_dir,
    target_size=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE),
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    subset='training' 
    )

val_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    base_dir,
    target_size=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE),
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, 
    subset='validation')
```

Here is the error

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-c8c878b374f7> in <module>()
     10     target_size=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE),
     11     batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
---> 12     subset='training'
     13     )
     14 

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/directory_iterator.py in __init__(self, directory, image_data_generator, target_size, color_mode, classes, class_mode, batch_size, shuffle, seed, data_format, save_to_dir, save_prefix, save_format, follow_links, subset, interpolation, dtype)
    104         if not classes:
    105             classes = []
--> 106             for subdir in sorted(os.listdir(directory)):
    107                 if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(directory, subdir)):
    108                     classes.append(subdir)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/.keras/datasets/Model_images_40'
```

I imagine this is something relatively trivial as I am very new to python and Colab notebooks and dont fully understand this code.

Comment: Can you confirm that the images are in the intended directory? Try `ls $base_dir`. Because you have not specified the folder during unzipping, it will unzip the archive in your current directory.

Comment: The files are not in that folder. When I run ls `$base_dir` I get `No such file or directory`. I thought. I thought I was specifying the directory with this line ... `base_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(zip_file), 'Model_images_40')`. Could you advise how to specify the directory please?

Comment: Ok, I have figured it out. It was a really silly oversight - I had the folder name wrong in this line `base_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(zip_file), 'Model_images_40')` Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm glad that you figured it out. :)